# How to add text content (after button click) to a webpage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

```js
const displayMessage = function (message) {
  document.querySelector('.message').textContent = message;
};

const displayOtherMessage = function (message) {
  document.querySelector('.otherMessage').textContent = message;
};

document.querySelector('.metric').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.enterheight').textContent =
    'Enter your height in metres.';
  const height = Number(document.querySelector('.height').value);
  console.log(height, typeof height);
  const weight = Number(document.querySelector('.weight').value);
  console.log(weight, typeof weight);
  if (!height && !weight) {
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent =
      'No height or weight entered.';
  } else if (height && weight) {
    const bmi = weight / height ** 2;
    document.querySelector('.message').textContent = `Your BMI is ${bmi}`;
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
      displayOtherMessage('You are underweight.');
    } else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
      displayOtherMessage('You are a healthy weight.');
    } else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30) {
      displayOtherMessage('You are overweight.');
    } else if (bmi >= 30 && bmi < 35) {
      displayOtherMessage('You are obese.');
    } else if (bmi > 35) {
      displayOtherMessage('You are morbidly obese.');
    } else {
      displayOtherMessage('');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <h2>BMI Calculator</h2>
      <h3>Would you like to use metric or imperial values?</h3>
      <div>
        <button id="metric" class="metric">Metric</button>
        <button id="imperial" class="imperial">Imperial</button>
      </div>
      <p id="enterheight"></p>
      <input type="number" class="height" />
      <p id="enterweight"></p>
      <input type="number" class="weight" />
      <p class="message"></p>
      <p class="otherMessage"></p>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm building BMI calculator in JavaScript that will eventually be able to take both metric and imperial values. When the "metric" button is clicked, I want the text "Enter your height in metres" to appear above the input field for height. Here's the JavaScript:

Basically, my issue is this:

```
document.querySelector('.enterheight').textContent =
    'Enter your height in metres.';
```

Currently, when the metric button is clicked, nothing happens. The console says that document.querySelector(...) is null, and I don't understand why. Is it because the HTML is an empty string, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Grumpy Karen you can also build a snippet here on site which the JS and html code to show the behavior

Answer (score 0):

In think, DOM element is not present in HTML. That's why JS can't be access. You need to create a element like

```
<p class="enterHeight"></p>
```

in HTML file, then you can access it..

I hope, it's useful for u...